# maven-assembly-plugin and eclipse Workspace resolution

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, m2e

I have a project, which uses the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to compile one JAR out of a number of projects.

I want to run the build with eclipse (Neon 4.6.3). When I run the build, I select the option `Resolve Workspace Artifacts`.

Resolving workspace artifacts seems to work fine for compiling the classes and testing. However, when it comes to executing the assembly into a JAR, **maven does not use the projects from the eclipse workspace but only projects in the local maven repository**.

Is there a way to make the maven-assembly-plugin also resolve the projects in the eclipse workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**maven-assembly-plugin does resolve workspace artifacts.**

I just had configuration issues in the workspace. Specifically, not ALL dependencies for the project were available in the workspace. After I had assured, that ALL dependencies can be resolved from the workspace, the maven-assembly-plugin collected the correct versions.

(You can check this by extending the *Maven Dependencies* under the project and assert that no *.jar dependencies are left to things which should be resolved from the eclipse projects).

Answer (score 0):

For any maven plugin errors in eclipse IDE, right click on project then select Maven -> Update Project -> select "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" -> Ok.